# cmd.exe | How to count files by specific format?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-line-interface

We use this to count files so far, but it counts all of them.

```
set count=0 & for %x in (*) do @(set /a count+=1 >nul)
echo %count%
```

What if the directory has 5 **.jpg** files, 5 **.png** files and 5 **.gif** files and we want to count just the *.jpg + .png* so the result of `echo %count%` would be 10 and not 15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list few wild card masks in `for` loop:

```
set count=0 & for %x in (*.jpg *.png) do @(set /a count+=1 >nul)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count all different extensions this way
(the first line only necessary after previous runs):

```
For /f "delims==" %x in ('set Ext[') Do @Set "%x="
for %x in (*) do @(set /a Ext[%~xx]+=1 >nul)
set Ext[
```

Sample output

```
Ext[.cmd]=2
Ext[.csv]=1
Ext[.ps1]=2
Ext[.txt]=1
Ext[]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach relying on the summary output of the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html):

```cmd
for /F %I in ('dir /-C /A:-D *.jpg *.png ^| find "File(s)"') do @set "FILES=%I"
echo %FILES%
```

On English systems, the last two lines returned by `dir` look similar to this:

> ```cmd
>                4 File(s)           4096 bytes
>                0 Dir(s)      4294963200 bytes free
> ```

The line containing `File(s)` is filtered out by the [`find`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) command and captured by a [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop.

---

Alternatively, you could [pipe](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) the output of `dir /B /A:-D` into `find /C` and capture the resulting count by `for /F`:

```cmd
for /F %I in ('dir /B /A:-D *.jpg *.png ^| find /C /V ""') do @set "FILES=%I"
echo %FILES%
```